# Rmd not knitting to HTML but giving a warning

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm very new to R and was trying to learn S3 OOP by creating my own generic method "Print" to print the dataframe. Its a very simple code it was knitting before but now it doesn't show results on HTML and gives me this warning -

```
myconstr= function(x,y,alpha){
  length(x) <- length(y)
  df = data.frame(x,y)
  #print(df)
  #print(alpha)
  t = t.test(x, y, alternative="two.sided", mu=0, paired=FALSE, var.equal=TRUE, conf.level = 1-alpha)
  class(t) ="Rttest"

  t
}
```

```
# now let us write our method
print.Rttest <- function(obj)
{
  x <- obj[["x"]]
  y <- obj[["y"]]
  df <- data.frame(x,y)
  library(kableExtra)
  kableExtra::kable(df,format = "html") %>%
  kable_styling()
}
```

```
library(sloop)
set.seed(21);x <-rnorm(30,5,2); set.seed(23); y<- rnorm(30, 3,2); alpha <- 0.05
obj <- myconstr(x = x, y = y, alpha = 0.05)
class(obj)
print(obj)
#s3_dispatch(print(obj))
```

This is the warning I'm getting and no results. If anyone can help me pinpoint where I'm wrong. I'll appreciate.

```
## Warning in !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output
## %in% : 'length(x) = 3 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

Comment: `obj` doesn't have elements named `x` and `y`, so both `obj[["x"]]` and `obj[["y"]]` are `NULL`.

Comment: So how would I access the dataframe to print in then method? It used to work before

Comment: The return value of `t.test` doesn't store its arguments `x` and `y`, so I'm not sure how it could have worked before.

Comment: You can use `x <- obj[["estimate"]][1];   y <- obj[["estimate"]][2]` in `print.Rttest`